# help needed to develop an algorithm

Tags: algorithm

hi i need a small help to develop an algorithm.. if there is any algorithm existing please update me.

this is what i want to do.

i have 4 input text box and one out put text box.
in input text box i want to give 4 characters. for an example a, a, a, b.
the output textbox should give me the answer "a".

i want to check what is the most entered character in the input textbox and want to display it.

sample input and output required (text1,text2,text3,text4  =  output)

```
a,a,a,a = a
a,b,a,a = a
a,a,b,b = a
a,a,b,a = a
c,c,a,c = c
```

this program is writing in c# with visual studio 2010 ultimate.. 
any good advise would be welcome....

thanks..

Comment: Please just don't ask for spoon-feed answers to your (home) work assignments. You'll definitely get more constructive answers/votes if you show what you have tried, explain where things go wrong and ask specific question regarding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i'll go with another tact; pseudo code. If you can't turn this into real code, go hand your textbook back to the teacher and tell him you're not suited to his class.

```
define dictionary with key as 'char' and value as integer
for each textbox
   read a character from textbox
   increment by 1 the dictionary value associated with this character
find the highest value in the dictionary
output the associated key
```

Answer (score 1):

If in doubt, use brute force. This means:

- set up a key-value collection that maps characters to counts
- step through your string; for each character, if it is in the collection, increase its count by 1, otherwise add it with a count of 1
- step through your collection to find the character with the highest count (remember highest-scoring character, for each entry, update remembered entry if current is better)

If your input were significantly larger (say 1000 characters), you'd have to go for a more efficient algorithm, but we're talking about four characters total.

Comment: can you give me some code how to do this.. please..

Comment: you asked for an algorithm, not code...

Comment: @FlaMM3R, provide some effort, develop a solution, and we'll help you where you're having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is very simple:

1. Iterate throuht textboxes:
2. Split textbox text by "," and interate throught
3. if you meet 'a' increase 'symbolACounter', if you meet 'b' increase 'symbolBCounter'
4. If symbolACounter > symbolBCounter, put'a' as answer, otherwise put 'b'
5. Go to next text box.

**EDIT:**

I haven't noticed there is 'c' as input. So, instead of counters it is better to have `Dictionary<char, int>` and do something like `charsDictionary[currentChar]++`;

Comment: can u provide me a code to do this. i spend 2 weeks to do this still i fail.it would be nice if you can provide some code..

Comment: which part are you having trouble with?